# GCM Missmatched messenger error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I call

```
instanceID.getToken(default_senderId, scope, null)
```

this function I saw IOException

```
Missmatched messenger
not posting request to register [package name] because of backoff period
java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="[package name]" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


      <service
            android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>
```

This is menifest part

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The "Missmatched messenger" here is not related, the important part is:

```
not posting request to register [package name] because of backoff period
```

This is logged when a getToken request gets blocked due to an exponential backoff to protect the InstanceId server. Essentially if a request to the server fails, a short backoff is set (of the order of seconds), where additional requests will be blocked. If after the initial backoff requests are still failing it will increase exponential.

This is to protect the Iid server from misbehaving clients, and to help avoid making any outages worse.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

Settings -> Application manager -> menu -> Reset app preferences -> Reset Apps

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi-variant gradle project you might want to check that the correct variant is selected (an incorrect variant without the correct manifest entries can result in this error)